Why is the range in audio is stuck in the middle


let progress = document.getElementById("progress");
let song = document.getElementById("song");
let ctrIcon = document.getElementById("ctrlIcon");

song.onloadedmetadata = function () {
  progress.max = song.duration;
  progress.value = song.curentTime;
};
function playPause() {
  if (ctrIcon.classList.contains("fa-pause")) {
    song.pause();
    ctrIcon.classList.remove("fa-pause");
    ctrIcon.classList.add("fa-play");
  } else {
    song.play();
    ctrIcon.classList.add("fa-pause");
    ctrIcon.classList.remove("fa-play");
  }
}

if (song.play()) {
  setInterval(() => {
    progress.value = song.curentTime;
  }, 500);
}

progress.onchange = function () {
  song.play();
  song.curentTime = progress.value;
  ctrIcon.classList.add("fa-pause");
  ctrIcon.classList.remove("fa-play");
};
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Poppins", "sans-serif";
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #333;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.music-player {
  background: #ffe0e5;
  width: 400px;
  padding: 25px 35px;
  text-align: center;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

nav .circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  background: #fff;
  color: #f53192;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(255, 26, 26, 0.22);
}

.song-img {
  width: 220px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 8px solid #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 60px rgba(255, 26, 26, 0.22);
}

.music-player h1 {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 400px;
  color: #333;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.music-player p {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #333;
}

#progress {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 6px;
  background: #f53192;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 40px 0;
}

#progress::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background-color: #f53192;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 8px solid #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 5px rgba(255, 26, 26, 0.22);
}

.controls {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.controls div {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 50px;
  color: #f53192;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(222, 26, 26, 0.22);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.controls div:nth-child(2) {
  transform: scale(1.5);
  background: #f53192;
  color: #fff;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Music Player</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script defer src="music.js"></script>
    <script
      src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/347a59382b.js"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="music-player">
        <nav>
          <div class="circle">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-angle-left"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="circle">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-bars"></i>
          </div>
        </nav>
        <img src="468-thumbnail.png" class="song-img" />
        <h1>Despacito</h1>
        <p>Luis Fonso Jamil</p>
        <audio controls id="song">
          <source src="audio.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
        </audio>
        <input type="range" id="progress" />
        <div class="controls">
          <div><i class="fa-solid fa-backward"></i></div>
          <div onclick="playPause()">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-play" id="ctrlIcon"></i>
          </div>
          <div><i class="fa-solid fa-forward"></i></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>



I am trying to make a custom range for my audio file but I do not know why the progress is stuck in the middle.
The progress does not move. I assigned it to the audio currentTime but it remained in the middle.
When I remove the Javascript it goes back to start but when I add back the JS code it
goes back to the middle. 

You have a typo, curentTime should be currentTime.


let progress = document.getElementById("progress");
let song = document.getElementById("song");
let ctrIcon = document.getElementById("ctrlIcon");

song.onloadedmetadata = function () {
  progress.max = song.duration;
  progress.value = song.currentTime;
};
function playPause() {
  if (ctrIcon.classList.contains("fa-pause")) {
    song.pause();
    ctrIcon.classList.remove("fa-pause");
    ctrIcon.classList.add("fa-play");
  } else {
    song.play();
    ctrIcon.classList.add("fa-pause");
    ctrIcon.classList.remove("fa-play");
  }
}

if (song.play()) {
  setInterval(() => {
    progress.value = song.currentTime;
    
  }, 500);
}

progress.onchange = function () {
  song.play();
  song.currentTime = progress.value;
  ctrIcon.classList.add("fa-pause");
  ctrIcon.classList.remove("fa-play");
};
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Poppins", "sans-serif";
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #333;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.music-player {
  background: #ffe0e5;
  width: 400px;
  padding: 25px 35px;
  text-align: center;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

nav .circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  background: #fff;
  color: #f53192;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(255, 26, 26, 0.22);
}

.song-img {
  width: 220px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 8px solid #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 60px rgba(255, 26, 26, 0.22);
}

.music-player h1 {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 400px;
  color: #333;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.music-player p {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #333;
}

#progress {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 6px;
  background: #f53192;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 40px 0;
}

#progress::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background-color: #f53192;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 8px solid #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 5px rgba(255, 26, 26, 0.22);
}

.controls {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.controls div {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 50px;
  color: #f53192;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(222, 26, 26, 0.22);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.controls div:nth-child(2) {
  transform: scale(1.5);
  background: #f53192;
  color: #fff;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Music Player</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script defer src="music.js"></script>
    <script
      src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/347a59382b.js"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="music-player">
        <nav>
          <div class="circle">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-angle-left"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="circle">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-bars"></i>
          </div>
        </nav>
        <img src="468-thumbnail.png" class="song-img" />
        <h1>Despacito</h1>
        <p>Luis Fonso Jamil</p>
        <audio controls id="song">
          <source src="https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-demos/DDR_assets/Kangaroo_MusiQue_-_The_Neverwritten_Role_Playing_Game.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
        </audio>
        <input type="range" id="progress" />
        <div class="controls">
          <div><i class="fa-solid fa-backward"></i></div>
          <div onclick="playPause()">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-play" id="ctrlIcon"></i>
          </div>
          <div><i class="fa-solid fa-forward"></i></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>




Thank you. Of course, current has two Rs.
